# My Custom made Seek Bar is not working Properly HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

I am making a video player in React.js I am trying to make custom seekbar with sync to video but my seek is not working properly as expected while user dragging see this GIF.Seek bar is not responding to the user movement it is going back to the origin position.Hope this Gif will help you to identify the problem

[image]

My React Code.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './index.css'

class SampleVideo extends Component{
    state = {
        play:false,
        pause:false,
        onHover:false,
        isMouseDown:false,
        seekedPercentage:"0%"
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.updateProgressBar, false);
    }
    updateProgressBar = () => {
        let percentage = Math.floor((100 / this.video.duration) * this.video.currentTime);
        this.setState({
            seekedPercentage:`${percentage}%`
        });
    };
    handleVideoPausePlay = () => {
      return this.state.play ? this.pause() : this.play();
    };
    play = () => {
        this.video.play();
        this.setState({
            play:true,
            pause:false
        })
    };
    pause = () => {
        this.video.pause()
        this.setState({
            play:false,
            pause:true
        })
    };
    handleSeek = e => {
        if(this.state.isMouseDown){
            console.log("Dragginf")

            let vid_duration = e.nativeEvent.offsetX / this.seek.offsetWidth;
            let percentage = vid_duration * 100;
            this.video.currentTime = vid_duration * this.video.duration;

            this.setState({
                seekedPercentage:`${percentage}%`
            })

        }else {
            console.log('i don;t Move ')
        }
    };
    handleMouseDown = e => {
        this.setState({ isMouseDown:true })
    };
    handleMouseUp = e => {
        this.setState({ isMouseDown:false });
    };
    render(){
       // console.log(this.state);
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div onMouseEnter={e => this.setState({onHover:true})} onMouseLeave={e => this.setState({ onHover:false })} className="video-wrapper">
                    <video ref={(c) => this.video = c} width="100%" height="100%" controls muted={true}>
                        <source src="vid/test.MKV" type="video/mp4" />
                        <source src="vid/test.MKV" type="video/ogg" />
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>

                    { this.state.onHover ?  <div className="video-controls-container">
                        <div className="vid-title">
                        </div>
                        <div className="vid-control">
                            <div className="vid-seekbar">
                                <div ref={s => this.seek = s} onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} onMouseMove={this.handleSeek}  className="video-seek-bar">
                                    <div style={{width:this.state.seekedPercentage}} className="videobarlevelbar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="seekControl">
                                        <div className="seekImage"><img src="/css/0d20f779-fd6f-49e2-903a-aed7380a00a2.webp" alt="dsvds" /></div>
                                        <div className="seekRound" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="vid-mini-controller">
                                { !this.state.play ? <div onClick={this.handleVideoPausePlay} className="play-btn">
                                    <svg height="32px" style={{enableBackground: 'new 0 0 24 32'}} version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 32" width="24px" xmlSpace="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Layer_1" /><g id="play"><polygon points="0,0 24,16 0,32  " style={{fill: '#fff'}} /></g></svg>
                                </div> : <div onClick={this.handleVideoPausePlay} className="pause-btn">
                                    <svg height="32px" id="svg2" width="32px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlSpace="preserve">
                                        <g id="background">
                                            <rect height="32" width="32" fill="none"/>
                                        </g>
                                        <g id="pause">
                                            <g>
                                                <rect fill="#fff" height="24" width="8" x="20" y="4"/>
                                                <rect fill="#fff" height="24" width="8" x="4" y="4"/>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
                                </div> }



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> : "" }





                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SampleVideo
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code without the css part, and it works fine on a video with the default html5 player. Does it work with a video or do you have the same issue ?
Could you post your css so I can give it a try ?